# Xcode Developer Tools folder is massive

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I ran out of space on my MacBook Air (128gb) so I started investigating the hard drive in order to find things I can get rid of. Obviously cleared the derived data and archives but I also found a folder I hadn't noticed before - `com.apple.DeveloperTools`and it takes 32gb (!!!!!!!!!) of space! that's crazy on a 128gb set up... Anyone knows something about this folder? Is it data that rebuilds itself once deleted? Can I do something about it?

Seems like it contains data of old Xcode versions...

Comment: Where is the folder?  Also a Macbook Air is not suitable for software development.

Comment: `private\var\folders\rj\TONSOFLETTERSANDNUMBERS\C\com.apple.DeveloperTools`. And that's what my workplace issued so no choice here..

Comment: That's a temporary directory and you should be removed during a reboot (AFAIK).

Comment: It has items that were last edited about two years ago.. The Mac was restarted hundreds of times since then haha. Should I try removing it?

Comment: Yeah I think so.  Do some searching about it first though.

Comment: First, thanks for your help. Second, StackOverflow was my last resort haha. Couldn't find anything about that online..

Answer (score 4):

I cleared that folder, and everything is fine.